# Secure cookies flag always getting lost in first session after resetting IIS

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, security, ssl, session-cookies

Looking for solution for ASP.NET_SessionId should always be secure flag true when request is from secure connection.

Below Steps are done to achieve -

1. Created MVC Project
2. Added below code under Global.asax.cs

```cs
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].HttpOnly = true;
      if (Request.IsSecureConnection) {
          Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Secure = true;
       }
   }
```

It works fine gives expected result. Here's is screenshot for secured flag.

**Screenshot**
[image]

To Reproduce Issue :

1. Delete Existing Cookies
2. Reset IIS
3. Load website in SSL

**4) Cookies of first session gets created is always remain Unsecure**
After the first session all session cookies remain secure.

**Here is screenshot for SSL request with unsecured cookies.**
[image]

May know the how to make sure cookies get remain secure while SSL request. Also it must be by code only.

Comment: Is there a redirect from http-->https on the first request?

Comment: No there no http to https redirect rule. Also from debug i can see Request.IsSecureConnection is true and also setting cookies to secure in first request. But still not found any solution